# Mock class in Python that is instantiated in constructor

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

**Situation**: I am writing a unit test for a class `B` in Python using the built-in unittest library. `B` instantiates another class `A` in its constructor. `B` roughly looks as follows:

```py
from app.module.a import A

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()

    def do_something(self):
        return self.a.get_something() + "/bar"
```

Let `A` simply be as follows:

```py
class A(object):
    def get_something():
        return "something"
```

In my unit test, I want to mock `A` completely. Up to now, my testing code looks as follows:

```py
from app.module.b import B
from unittest import TestCase, mock

class TestB(object):
    @mock.patch('app.module.a.A')
    def test_do_something(self, a_mock):
        a_mock.get_something.return_value = 'foo'
        b = B()  # (1)
        self.assertEqual(b.do_something(), "foo/bar")  # (2)
```

**Problem**: The assertion at (2) fails because the expression `b.do_something()` returns "something/bar" instead of "foo/bar". This means, that at (1) `A` was not mocked during the construction of the `B` instance.

**Question**: How can I achieve that `B` does not construct an instance of the real `A`, but uses the mock instead?

*Note*: I am aware that this tight coupling of `A` and `B` might not be optimal. I need to write tests for the code of someone else and do not want to refractor his code base at this point.

Comment: You have to mock where you import `A` into, not where you import it from.

Comment: Does that mean that the only possibility is to mock `A` in `app/module/b.py`? That would mean, I have to refractor the code of my colleague to support dependency injection at this point.

Comment: But if that's the case, how does the mocking of `requests.post` then work? I have a test method where that method is mocked, although it is imported to another file and the method call occurs somewhere deep down in the call stack. How is this different?

Comment: I think it means that you can do this `@mock.patch('app.module.b.A')` since there is an "A" in "b", as far as Python is concerned (as long as you have done `from a import A` inside of b.py).

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thank you!